# Windows Phone background agent Microsoft.Phone.dll submission issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, background-agents

I am trying to submit an app to the app hub, whick is using a backgound agent to update the app tile. the background agent requires to use the Microsoft.Phone.dll, but when I submit the app i get the following errors

> 2011: The background agent can’t use
>   Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTile::Create, which assembly TileAgent.dll
>   is trying to use. Update your file and then try again.
>
> 2011: The background agent can’t use
>   System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement::Pause, which assembly
>   Microsoft.Phone.dll is trying to use. Update your file and then try
>   again.
>
> 2011: The background agent can’t use
>   System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement::Stop, which assembly
>   Microsoft.Phone.dll is trying to use. Update your file and then try
>   again.
>
> 2011: The background agent can’t use
>   System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement::Play, which assembly
>   Microsoft.Phone.dll is trying to use. Update your file and then try
>   again.
>
> 2011: The background agent can’t use
>   System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement::set_Position, which assembly
>   Microsoft.Phone.dll is trying to use. Update your file and then try
>   again.
>
> 2011: The background agent can’t use
>   System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement::set_AutoPlay, which assembly
>   Microsoft.Phone.dll is trying to use. Update your file and then try
>   again.
>
> 2011: The background agent can’t use
>   System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement, which assembly
>   Microsoft.Phone.dll is trying to use. Update your file and then try
>   again.
>
> 2011: The background agent can’t use
>   System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement::SetSource, which assembly
>   Microsoft.Phone.dll is trying to use. Update your file and then try
>   again.
>
> 2011: The background agent can’t use System.Windows.Media.VideoBrush,
>   which assembly Microsoft.Phone.dll is trying to use. Update your file
>   and then try again.
>
> 2011: The background agent can’t use
>   System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement::.ctor, which assembly
>   Microsoft.Phone.dll is trying to use. Update your file and then try
>   again.

although I am not using any of those assemblies, or reference them anywhere in the agent's project.
please help!

**EDIT**: I removed the create tile method, and now this error is gone. the rest though remain the same, although I am not using any of them
There is absolutely no use of the System.Widnows.Contols in this project

**EDIT**: Here is the list of referenced i have in the agent's project

```
Microsoft.Phone
mscorelib
mscorelib.extensions
system
System.Core
System.Net
System.Windows
System.Xml
```

Comment: And what if you remove System.Windows reference??

Comment: i need it, i have by default this in my agent Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
                {
                    Application.Current.UnhandledException += ScheduledAgent_UnhandledException;
                });

Comment: i removed system.core, mscorelib and mscorelib.extensions, still the same errors

Comment: It's magic :) Try to unload all other projects and let your application contains only bg agent.

Comment: when i have it with another completely empty app, i get no errors!!

Comment: And now you need to find the "bad" project. Add them one-by-one.

Comment: honestly i cannot understand this. all i do is reference the agents project, in one ap this is ok, in another its not. i dont do absilutely anything, i dont even call the agent, just a reference

Comment: How do you call the reference to bgagent project? From with project?

Comment: references - > right click -> add reference -> the agents project. thats all i did in both windows phone solutions, one is ok, the other full of errors (i first add existing project in the solution, the agents project)

Comment: And you do it only from Main project, do you?

Comment: How many classes are located in BgAgent project? Do you use any classes from other projects in agent class?

Comment: no, no other classes, i am following all the samples i found about it, i have one agent, call the update tile method, give title and image url for the tile. thats all the agent does.

Comment: omg i think it worked now. i changed the location of the agent's project, added it again as an existing project, reference it, and no errors

Comment: my congratulations :) Hope my answer was helpful for you.

Comment: i am going to mark your question as answer, its working finally!! thank you  Anton so much for your time today!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your agent has some references to code wich uses listed API.
For example:

You have some class wich creates new tile. `Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTile::Create`. And your  background agent lives in the same proj, or your bg agent uses code wich lives in proj where you create new tile.

Some illustration:

**proj A**

```
 //draws tile 
 public class TileBuilder() {}
 //creates new tile using TileBuilder() 
 public class NewTileManager(TileBuilder tBuilder) 
 {
 }
```

**proj B**

```
  public class ScheduledAgent : ScheduledTaskAgent
  {
      protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
      {
        //update data
        var tBuilder = new TileBuilder(); // oops, you use code from proj A. 
                                          // So, you have it
                                          // as a reference, And MS thinks that 
                                          // your bgAgent uses forbidden API

      }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Anton. I solved the problem with the create method error, I cannot find a solution for the rest. I simply dont use System.Widnows.Contols  anywhere, i just use 2 strings, one for the title and one the image link for the tile update, that's it

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have a video controls. Play\pause logic. Am I right?

Comment: not in my agent project, nowhere. i just create new tiledata and update a tile with 2 strings. the windows phone project, which is using the agent has video, i tried removing it, but it has no connection with these errors, still the same output

Comment: i did this, i also totally deleted the output in bin to be sure and rebuilt it

Comment: also i created an new agent from scratch, and added the tile update method in there, still the same errors

Comment: the weird thing is, this app runs perfectly when installed on 2 wp7 devices and on the emulator, too, i am starting to believe this is amarketplace bug

Comment: Do you have xaml files in this proj?

Comment: Also, before submitting to the marketplace run this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394032(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: i dont see anything with more info there, just a list same as above

Comment: Ok, add to the question the list of projects referenced to your agent proj.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use some APIs from a scheduled task.

See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962(v=vs.92).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202962%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: yes i know, i dont use them! i did have a crate thethod for a tile, which i removed, but the rest, simply dont even exist in the background agent's project

Comment: Are you still referencing some restricted libraries in your background agent project?

Comment: nope", thats why i'm so confused, i dont need them and i dont use them. i searched the whole project again and again, no reference, nothing

Comment: it says that the assembly Microsoft.Phone.dll is trying to use them, but i dont know how and why it is trying to use them

Comment: And you don't reference another project in your solution that might use them?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I have a hacky solution. You can't use those methods in a background agent. If you would really like to do so, use reflection. But make sure that you don't actually call any of that code from the background task, as this would not be allowed.

For example, for ShellTile.Create:

```
 using System.Reflection;

   ...

      Uri NavUri = //your tile's navigation URI
      ShellTileData data = //your tile's data

      object[] parameters = { NavUri, data};
      Type[] types = new[] { typeof(Uri), typeof(ShellTileData)};
      Type type = typeof(ShellTile);
      MethodInfo info = type.GetMethod("Create", types);
      info.Invoke(null, parameters);
```

That will trick the Dev Center into accepting your xap.